# Mutable copy of a CoreFundation Reference type

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, core-foundation

In xcode4/Objective C, on Leopard:

I have a `CGDisplayModeRef` which is as I understand it an Immutable Dictionary Reference. 
I need to modify this so I tried to get a mutable copy like this:

```
 CGDisplayModeRef displayMode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
 NSMutableDictionary * displayModeMutable = 
                   [((NSDictionary *)&displayMode) mutableCopy];
```

Strangely enough I get a dictionary containing my App delegate back! 
What is the correct way to do this?

By the way I want to set the refresh rate for a CRT display to 100 Hz which I know the hardware supports but Leopard thinks it does not! So I need to manually change the refresh rate in the "displayMode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a CGDisplayModeRef which is as I understand it an Immutable Dictionary Reference

No I don't think so; you confuse the 10.5 function `CGDisplayCurrentMode` which returns `CFDictionaryRef`, and the 10.6 function `CGDisplayModeRef`. The latter is **not** a `CFDictionaryRef`.

The only thing supported using 10.6 functions is to get the list of available modes via `CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes`, choose one which suites your purpose, and set it back with `CGDisplaySetDisplayMode`. As a preparation for future expansion, `CGDisplaySetDisplayMode` accepts the options as `CFDictionaryRef`, but you can't use it currently.

By the way, even when you cast a `CFDictionaryRef` to `NSDictionary`, you have one too many `&`. A `...Ref` is already a pointer, so

```
CFDictionaryRef a;
NSDictionary* b=(NSDictionary*)a;
```

should suffice. You shouldn't use `(NSDictionary*)&a`.

Comment: Thanks, You are absolutely correct about the     '&'    . I thought if I modify the Display mode that I get back and change the refresh rate I might be able to set the monitor to something above what OSX thinks it supports (and I know that it does).  I can use either Leopard or Snow Leopard.